SwiftUI Fetching data cancelled when refreshing a task
When I'm fetching data from a remote server using the .task modifier and then trying to refresh the said data with the .refreshable modifier in a ScrollView gives me an error:

NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"

The offending code is this:
import SwiftUI

struct Podcasts: View {
    private let podcastProvider = PodcastProvider()

    @State private var isLoading = false
    @State private var podcasts: [Podcast] = []

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                if self.isLoading {
                    ProgressView()
                }
                ForEach(self.podcasts) { item in
                    Text(item.name)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            await self.refreshData()
        }
        .refreshable {
            await self.refreshData()
        }
    }

    private func refreshData() async {
        self.isLoading = true
        self.podcasts = try await self.podcastProvider.fetchPocasts()
        self.isLoading = false
    }
}

Here's the complete error:

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://foobar.com/podcasts, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://foobar.com/podcasts, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=("LocalDataTask <1344CDC5-EAB0-4FC3-9EAE-A74233B04C75>.<30>"), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <1344CDC5-EAB0-4FC3-9EAE-A74233B04C75>.<30>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}

I thought the answer was the same I can find in this answer:
Why is async task cancelled in a refreshable Modifier on a ScrollView (iOS 16)
but none of the answers I've replicated can help.
I suspect something fishy involving the @State, but I'm really unsure why
EDIT:
I cannot push the actual implementation of the PodcastProvider as it has many details of the client/server authentication. But even with this mock code
import Foundation

@MainActor
class PodcastProvider {
    func fetchPocasts(for type: StreamType) async throws -> [Podcast] {
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64.random(in: 100_000_000 ... 500_000_000))
        
        let items = [
            Podcast(name: "foo", alias: "foo", description: nil, image: nil),
            Podcast(name: "bar", alias: "bar", description: nil, image: nil),
            Podcast(name: "kazoo", alias: "kazoo", description: nil, image: nil)
        ]
       
        return items
    }
}

... the cancellation error appears.
EDIT 2:
The comment from lorem ipsum gave me the correct culprit for the problem. Is the conditional show for the ProgressView()
Still I don't understand why.

Can you show a [mcve], some code I can directly copy and paste into Xcode and reproduce the problem?

@Sweeper I've edited the question with more details

Your mock code does not output cancellation errors.

Your Provider is likely not pure async/await or something else is redrawing everything

@loremipsum you are the MVP. The real implementation shows a loading widget in the page. That is the culprit. Your comment put me in the right direction. I'll edit the question so one of you can add an answer

You may also want to set a breakpoint at the call in the task modifier and see under which scenarios it get called. The task modifier will be called whenever the actual  renderable view appears - and this can happen when we don't expect it, due to changes of the "identity" of the associated SwiftUI struct.

The size of the ScrollView is changing sometimes that can cancel tasks. Attach the task to the ProgressView and make the default value for isLoading true.

Sorry for the delay, the sum of all your comments gave me the right way to solve the problem. Thank you all!

It might be because you put the .task and .refreshable on the same View so they will conflict with each other, this works for me:
    var body: some View {
        if products.isEmpty { // or perhaps first load complete would be a better check
            ProgressView()
                .task {
                    await refreshData()
                }
        }
        else {
            List(products) { product in
                Text(product.title)
            }
            .refreshable {
                await refreshData()
            }
        }
    }

You you've got a memory leak you can fix by changing PodcastProvider from a class to a struct. Usually also an async controller like this would not be @MainActor.
I haven't tested this but perhaps making the podcasts array optional would be a neat way to check for initial load complete, e.g.
@State var podcasts: [Podcast]? = nil
...
if let podcasts {
    List(podcasts) {
    .refreshable ...
}
else {
    ProgressView()
    .task ...
}

